# LIBSDL2 + DirectFB + i.MX 6 - Only software blitting?

Tags: yocto, sdl-2, imx6, directfb

At the moment we are developing an SDL2 app on an embeddedboard (i.MX 6) with DirectFB. Our LinuxOS is generated via YOCTO. The application itself works fine, bit on `SDL_RenderPresent( renderer_ )` there seems only software blitting is working, which takes the CPU upto the limit.

- Window ( 256 x 128 px ): 60 FPS - ~20% at one core
- Window ( 1280 x 1024 px ): 45 FPS - 100% at one core

Adding `no-software` to the DFBARGS takes the CPU usage down to ~6% (which is acceptable), but after that nothing is visible at the screen anymore. This is because I think SDL2/DirectFB is using only software blitting in this case. Did i forgot a flag in initializing?

*Running a qt5-Application at 1280x1024 with 60FPS takes ~3-6% CPU usage of one core.*

### Creation of objects

```
window_ = SDL_CreateWindow( "", 0, 0, 256, 128, 0 );

renderer_ = SDL_CreateRenderer( window_, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );
```

### Some outputs from DirectFB

#### fbset:

```
mode "1280x1024-0"
        # D: 0.000 MHz, H: 0.000 kHz, V: 0.000 Hz
        geometry 1280 1024 1280 1024 32
        timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        accel true
        rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode
```

#### dfbdump:

```
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'SigHandler' (411) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.7.7 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2012-2015  DirectFB integrated media GmbH
        (c) 2001-2015  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2020-04-01 09:36)
(*) Direct/Memcpy: Using libc memcpy()
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Fusion Dispatch' (412) [MESSAGING - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Switcher' (415) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Flusher' (416) [DEFAULT - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) DRMKMS/Init: using device /dev/dri/card0 (default)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'DRMKMS/Buffer' (417) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/Graphics: nsc NSC GX1/GX2 driver version 1.1 (NSC)
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: Got 1 connectors, 1 encoders
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: found connected connector id 38.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: connector 38 is already bound to encoder 37.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: encoder 37 is already bound to ctrc 28.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: Default mode is 1280x1024, we have 16 modes in total
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: supported properties for layer id 29
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: supported properties for layer id 34
(*) DirectFB/Core/WM: Default 0.3 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Genefx' (418) [DEFAULT - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
Dependent NSC Kernel FrameBuffer driver version is 2.7.7 or later

DirectFB uptime: 01:02:30

-----------------------------[ Surfaces ]--------------------------------------------
Reference   FID  . Refs  Width Height  Format     ID     Video   System  Capabilities
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N/A              :   3   1280 x 1024       ARGB     1  10240k       0k   video only   double
                                                       ------   ------
                                                       10240k       0k   -> 10240k total

----------------------------------[ Contexts of Layer 0 ]----------------------------------------
Reference   FID  . Refs  Width Height Format   Location on screen  Regions  Active  Info    Level
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N/A              :   2   1280 x 1024  ARGB     0.0, 0.0 -> 1.0, 1.0    1     (*)    SHARED   N/A
 (!!!)  *** UNIMPLEMENTED [fusion_dispatch] *** [../../../DirectFB-1.7.7/lib/fusion/fusion.c:3947]
```

#### dfbinfo:

```
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'SigHandler' (427) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.7.7 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2012-2015  DirectFB integrated media GmbH
        (c) 2001-2015  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2020-04-01 09:36)
(*) Direct/Memcpy: Using libc memcpy()
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Fusion Dispatch' (428) [MESSAGING - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Switcher' (431) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Flusher' (432) [DEFAULT - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
(*) DRMKMS/Init: using device /dev/dri/card0 (default)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'DRMKMS/Buffer' (433) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8388608>...
Dependent NSC Kernel FrameBuffer driver version is 2.7.7 or later
(*) DirectFB/Graphics: nsc NSC GX1/GX2 driver version 1.1 (NSC)
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: Got 1 connectors, 1 encoders
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: found connected connector id 38.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: connector 38 is already bound to encoder 37.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: encoder 37 is already bound to ctrc 28.
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: Default mode is 1280x1024, we have 16 modes in total
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: supported properties for layer id 29
(*) DirectFB/DRMKMS: supported properties for layer id 34
(*) DirectFB/Core/WM: Default 0.3 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Genefx' (434) [DEFAULT - OTHER/0] <8388608>...


Screen (00) DRMKMS Screen                   (primary screen)
   Caps: MIXERS ENCODERS OUTPUTS

   Mixer (0) DRMKMS Mixer
     Caps:                    FULL SUB_LAYERS
     Layers (full mode):      (00) (01) (02)
     Layers (sub mode):  0 of (00) (01) (02)


   Encoder (0) DRMKMS Encoder
     Type:           DIGITAL
     Caps:           FREQUENCY RESOLUTION
     Output Resolutions: 640_480 800_600 1024_768 1152_864 1280_1024


   Output (0) DRMKMS Output
     Caps:       RESOLUTION
     Resolutions: 640_480 800_600 1024_768 1152_864 1280_1024
     Signals:    HDMI


     Layer (00) DRMKMS Layer                    (primary layer)
        Type:    GRAPHICS
        Caps:    SURFACE

     Layer (01) DRMKMS Plane Layer 0
        Type:    GRAPHICS
        Caps:    SURFACE ALPHACHANNEL SCREEN_POSITION

     Layer (02) DRMKMS Plane Layer 1
        Type:    GRAPHICS
        Caps:    SURFACE ALPHACHANNEL SCREEN_POSITION


 (!!!)  *** UNIMPLEMENTED [fusion_dispatch] *** [../../../DirectFB-1.7.7/lib/fusion/fusion.c:3947]
```